# PHP input create function with array arguments

Tags: php

I would like to create an input create function in class, that i could create inputs like this:

```
$form->input('name'=>'firstname', 'type'=>'text', 'placeholder'=>'Put your name here');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code-on-demand service, you need to show some effort in solving the problem yourself first.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to do it, i need just a solution, not all written code.

Comment: Are you using any particular framework? You should consider using some pre-made form building components rather than creation all of your own functions. The Symfony Form component might be a good start: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: Try treating the parameters as an array, and write a function which iterates over the array to generate the HTML input fields. Then abstract that function into a class.

Comment: php framework using is good idea?